# How to get specific word in an Email thanks to regex and insert that word in a file name with Outlook VBA?

Tags: regex, vba, outlook

I would like to get specific word inside an Email (should be the signature of the Email) and store that word in a file name thanks to Outlook VBA.

I already have something that work to add the date in the file name but I would like to add the name (from the signature) from whom the Email has been sent.

This is the part that already work:

```
Public Sub Process_SAU(Item As Outlook.MailItem)

Dim object_attachment As Outlook.Attachment
 
Dim saveFolder As String
' Folder location when I want to save my file
saveFolder = "C:\Users\gdeange1\Desktop\suggestion updates\UpdateBusinessInformation\Processed_By_Bulks"
       For Each object_attachment In Item.Attachments
' Criteria to save .doc files only
    If InStr(object_attachment.DisplayName, ".json") Then
 
        object_attachment.SaveAsFile saveFolder & "\" & Format(Now(), "dd-mm-yyyy") & "_" & object_attachment.DisplayName

    End If
 
    Next

End Sub
```

And I found something that could do the trick:

```
Function ExtractText(Str As String) ' As String
 Dim regEx As New RegExp
 Dim NumMatches As MatchCollection
 Dim M As Match
 
'this pattern looks for 4 digits in the subject
 regEx.Pattern = "((.*))[A-Z]{0}(Danièle Loubert|Véronique Mantha|Julie-Emmanuelle Carle|Nicolas Bertrand|Martine Jean)"

' use this if you need to use different patterns.
' regEx.Pattern = regPattern

 Set NumMatches = regEx.Execute(Str)
 If NumMatches.Count = 0 Then
      ExtractText = ""
 Else
 Set M = NumMatches(0)
     ExtractText = M.SubMatches(0)
 End If
 code = ExtractText
End Function
```

I tried something like this :

```
Public Sub Process_SAU(Item As Outlook.MailItem)
 
Function ExtractText(Str As String) ' As String
 Dim regEx As New RegExp
 Dim NumMatches As MatchCollection
 Dim M As Match
 
'this pattern looks for 4 digits in the subject
 regEx.Pattern = "((.*))[A-Z]{0}(Danièle Loubert|Véronique Mantha|Julie-Emmanuelle Carle|Nicolas Bertrand|Martine Jean)"

' use this if you need to use different patterns.
' regEx.Pattern = regPattern

 Set NumMatches = regEx.Execute(Str)
 If NumMatches.Count = 0 Then
      ExtractText = ""
 Else
 Set M = NumMatches(0)
     ExtractText = M.SubMatches(0)
 End If
 code = ExtractText

Public Sub Process_SAU(Item As Outlook.MailItem)

Dim object_attachment As Outlook.Attachment
 
Dim saveFolder As String
' Folder location when I want to save my file
saveFolder = "C:\Users\gdeange1\Desktop\suggestion updates\UpdateBusinessInformation\Processed_By_Bulks"
       For Each object_attachment In Item.Attachments
' Criteria to save .doc files only
    If InStr(object_attachment.DisplayName, ".json") Then
 
        object_attachment.SaveAsFile saveFolder & "\" & Format(Now(), "dd-mm-yyyy") & "_" & code & "_" & object_attachment.DisplayName

    End If
 
    Next

End Function
End Sub
```

But I got an error : Compile Error -> Expected End Sub

Now can I mix both of these codes in order to have my file name something like this :

```
object_attachment.SaveAsFile saveFolder & "\" & Format(Now(), "dd-mm-yyyy") & "_" & code & "_" & object_attachment.DisplayName
```

That would give for example: 23-02-2021_Martine Jean_update.json (I'don't if the space has to be removed).

Thank you in advance for your help, really appreciate it!

G

UPDATED (Not sure that this work)

```
 Public Sub Process_SAU(Item As Outlook.MailItem)

Dim object_attachment As Outlook.Attachment
 
Dim saveFolder As String
Dim Code As Code
' Folder location when I want to save my file
saveFolder = "C:\Users\gdeange1\Desktop\suggestion updates\UpdateBusinessInformation\Processed_By_Bulks"
       For Each object_attachment In Item.Attachments
' Criteria to save .doc files only
    If InStr(object_attachment.DisplayName, ".json") Then
 
        object_attachment.SaveAsFile saveFolder & "\" & Format(Now(), "dd-mm-yyyy") & "_" & Code & "_" & object_attachment.DisplayName

    End If
 
    Next

End Sub

Function ExtractText(Str As String) ' As String
 Dim regEx As New RegExp
 Dim NumMatches As MatchCollection
 Dim M As Match

 regEx.Pattern = "((.*))[A-Z]{0}(Danièle Loubert|Véronique Mantha|Julie-Emmanuelle Carle|Nicolas Bertrand|Martine Jean)"



 Set NumMatches = regEx.Execute(Str)
 If NumMatches.Count = 0 Then
      ExtractText = ""
 Else
 Set M = NumMatches(0)
     ExtractText = M.SubMatches(0)
 End If
 Code = ExtractText
 End Function
```

Comment: It sounds you like have the full game plane lined up. Have you tried what you shared? What was the issue? Error? If so, what error? Wrong output? If so, can you share samples?

Comment: I have added all script with the issue above (Compile Error : Expected End Sub) I tried adding another End Sub at the bottom but didn't change anything.

Comment: You are storing your subs and functions inside a single sub. They need to be separate. You should have your main sub that calls the appropriate subs & functions with variables being passed correctly

Comment: The function is a standalone sub. What you have `Sub Process_SAU ( Function ExtractText (.... ) End Function ) End Sub` is invalid

Comment: Thanks for your help @urdearboy !! I just started VBA a couple of days ago.. would you share an example of what it woud looks like ? Thanks in advance, appreciate your support and time!

Comment: Your main macro should be calling `ExtractText`, not `Code`. You need `ExtractText - M.SubMatches(0)`. The variable `Code` dies inside the function and does not carry forward. The value stored in `ExtractText` does carry forward

Comment: I tried adding this in the main macro but no success yet:

`Dim Code As ExtractText.Code

' Folder location when I want to save my file
saveFolder = "C:\Users\gdeange1\Desktop\suggestion updates\UpdateBusinessInformation\Processed_By_Bulks"
       For Each object_attachment In Item.Attachments
' Criteria to save .doc files only
    If InStr(object_attachment.DisplayName, ".json") Then
 
        object_attachment.SaveAsFile saveFolder & "\" & Format(Now(), "dd-mm-yyyy") & "_" & Code & "_" & object_attachment.DisplayName

    End If
 
    Next

End Sub`

Answer (score 1):

Functions and subs should be seperated into their own procedures. Here is an example where there is a main sub that calls a function. Note the sub passes the input to the function which ends up bringing the output to your sub.

Notice each macro stands alone. You do not nest the entire code for the function inside your main macro

```
Sub Master_Macro()

    Dim Output As Double

    'Call Function with Input

    'Work with output in current sub
    Output = Add_10(30)
    MsgBox Output

End Sub
```

---

```
Public Function Add_10(Target As Double) As Double

    'Takes a input (Target) and returns value + 10
    Add_10 = Target + 10

End Function
```

---

With the code you shared, start with the first macro and simply call the function while passing in the right parameter. From there, the idea you suggested would work.

Comment: Thanks for the details, I've added a new version as answer above.

Comment: do you think that what I post in the UPDATED part (on my post) could work? I tried and it failed with Compile Error -> Argument not Optionnal